# Pandas groupby on one column, aggregate on second column, preserve third column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1': (1,1,1,2), 'key2': (1,2,3,1), 'data1': ("test","test2","t","test")})
```

I want to group by key1 and have the min of data1. Further I want to preserve the according value of key2 without grouping on it.

```
df.groupby(['key1'], as_index=False)['data1'].min()
```

gets me:

```
key1 data1  
1    t  
2    test
```

but I need:

```
key1 key2 data1  
1    3    t  
2    1    test
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you calculate the `min` of a string?

Comment: @EdChum min() works for strings as "t" < "test"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `groupby.apply` and retrieve all instances where `x['data1']==x['data1'].min()` equals to `True` while preserving the non-grouped columns as shown:

```
df.groupby('key1', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x[x['data1'].eq(x['data1'].min())])
```

[image]

---

To know what elements return `True`, from which we subset the reduced `DF` later:

```
df.groupby('key1').apply(lambda x: x['data1'].eq(x['data1'].min()))

key1   
1     0    False
      1    False
      2     True
2     3     True
Name: data1, dtype: bool
```